# Regex - how to exclude a specific string that contains a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to exclude **whole** specific **string** that contains on of these characters: **$ % &**

The string looks like a URL. It should starts with 'http(s)://', 'ftp://' or 'www.' and match everything after it accept invalid characters **$ % &**

------- For example:------- 
**Valid strings are:** 
www.localhost 
http://www.aaaaaa.com/aaaaa5-test5 
https://map:1234 
www.google.com 
http://map:1234 

**Invalid strings are:** 
http://www.aaaaa%a.com/test5 
https://map:12$34 
www.google.com&

I have written this regex (https://regex101.com/r/Gl60ls/1)

```
/(\b(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.).+?([^\$\%\&\s\n])+)/gim
```

But it match first part of the string till the invalid character

------- For example: ------- 
If I have a string http://www.aaaaa%a.com/test5 , it will match http://www.aaaaa 
I need to **completely exclude** the entire string

Any ideas ? I will be so grateful !

Comment: Standard URL validation is not suitable because we have only 3 invalid characters.

Comment: Can i ask why isn't enough for the function to determine whether it matches or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `.+?([^\$\%\&\s\n])+)` will match as soon as at least *one* character is not in your "forbidden" list. It is not forbidding those characters to be matched in the `.+?` part.

You can use negative look-ahead for your purpose:

[`(^(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)(?!.*?[$%&]).+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Gl60ls/2)

If you have several URLs on the same line, separated by a space, then:

[`\b(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)([^$%&\s]+)(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/Gl60ls/4)

Comment: What if we have a few URLs separated by spacebar.
For examle:
"https://www.aaaaa%a.com/test5 http://www.aaaa.com/test http://www.aaaaa&a.com"
And only second URL sould be matched as soon as it is the only one valid

Comment: See addition to answer.